# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'email'. Flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, attributeerror

i've a strange problem...

i do this:

```
  if request.method=="POST":

        email = request.form["email"]
        session["email"] = email

        found_user = users.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        found_user.email = email
        db.session.commit()
```

and gives me this problem:

```
        found_user.email = email
        AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'email'
```

Who can help me??
thanks <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it means it didn't find any users matching your filter